# What's the best practice to implement "read receipts" on group chats in AWS AppSync and Amplify?

Tags: concurrency, chat, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, real-time-updates

I'm building an Angular 11 web app using AppSync for the backend.

I've mentioned group chat, but basically I have a feature in my app where I have an announcement feature where there's a person creating announcements to a specific audience (can be individual members or groups of members) and whenever the receiving user opens the announcement, it has to mark that announcement as read for that user in their UI and also let the sender know that it has been opened by that particular member.

I have an idea for implementing this:-

1. Each announcement needs to have a "seenBy" which aggregates the user Ids of the ones who open it.
2. Each member also has an attribute in their user object named "announcementsRead" which is an array of Ids of the announcements that they have opened.
3. In the UI when I'm gathering the list of announcements for the user, the ones whose ID don't belong in the member's own announcementsRead array, will be marked as unread.
4. When they click on it and it is opened, I make 2 updates - a) To the announcement object I simply push the member's user ID to the "seenBy" attribute and push to db. b) to the member's user object, I add the announcement's id to the "announcementRead" attribute and push it to the DB.

This is just something that I came up with.

Please let me know if there are any pitfalls to this approach. Or if there are simpler ways to achieve this functionality.

I have a few concerns as well:-

1. Let's say that two users are opening an announcement at the same time, and the clients try to update the announcement with the updated seenBy containing the user's ID, what happens when the two requests from two different clients are happening concurrently? It's possible that the first user fetches the object and then the second user fetches it immediately, and by the time the second user has updated the attribute and sent it back to the DB, the first user has already written their updated data. In such a case the second user's write to the DB will overwrite the first user's change. I am not sure of the internal mechanisms of the amplify data store, but I can imagine this happening. Is this possible? If so, how do we ensure that it is prevented?
2. Is it really necessary for me to maintain the "announcementsRead" attribute in the user? I mean I can imagine generating that list in the UI every time I get the list of announcements by checking if the current user's ID exists in the announcement's "seenBy" and maintaining that list in the UI, that way we can eliminate redundancy of info in the DB and also it would make sense to not accumulate extremely old announcement IDs that may have been deleted. But I'm wondering if having this on the member actually helps in an indispensable way.

Hope my questions are clear.